# Change dynamic subfolder to subdomain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic

I want rewrite this url:

*sitename.com/cat/**cat2**/page.html*

to

***cat2***.sitename.com

cat2 dynamically, by dropdown list.

Is this possible by htaccess file or no ?

This is Flynax CMS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect requests to www.example.com/blog to blog.example.com, try this.

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog/ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error